# How to change the form instance dynamically from the data entered at the previous step

Tags: python, django

I would like from the data entered in the form to check if the person exists in the database if yes we skip the registration form to another form. Alas my code does not work. Someone can help me.

Forms :

```html
FORMS = [
         ("stage1-1", RegisterIdentification),
         ("stage1-2", RecRegister),
         ("stage2-1", BirthIdentification),
         ("stage2-2", RecBirth),
         ("stage3-1", FatherIdentification),
         ("stage3-2", RecFather),
         ("stage4-1", MotherIdentification),
         ("stage4-2", RecMother),
]
```

Templates

```html
TEMPLATES = {
        "stage1-1": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage1-1.html",
        "stage1-2": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage1-2.html",
        "stage2-1": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage2-1.html",
        "stage2-2": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage2-2.html",
        "stage3-1": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage3-1.html",
        "stage3-2": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage3-2.html",
        "stage4-1": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage4-1.html",
        "stage4-2": "fr/public/births-wizard/stage4-2.html",
}
```

Views :

```html
class BirthsWizard(SessionWizardView):
instance = None
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    """
        change the form or the step instance dynamically from the data we entered
        at the previous step
    """
    # get the default form
    form = super(BirthsWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

    if step is None:
        step = self.steps.current

    if step == 'stage1-2':
        # get prev datas and chek if they are in Database
        step1_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('stage1-1')
        register_doctype = step1_data.get('registerDoctype')
        register_nationality = step1_data.get('registerNationality')
        register_idNum = step1_data.get('registeridNum')
        if register_doctype and register_nationality and register_idNum:
            check_register = BirthsDeclarer.objects.filter(doctype=register_doctype,
                                                           nationality=register_nationality,
                                                           idNum=register_idNum)
            if check_register:
              # if  prev datas are in Database jump to a specific step
                form_name = "stage2-1"
                form = form_name

    return form


def get_template_names(self):
    return TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]

@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(BirthsWizard, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)




def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    # i will process data here 
    return render(self.request, 'fr/public/births-wizard/done.html', {'form_data': [ form.cleaned_data for form in form_list ] })
```

```html
Result: the page  displays without the form
```

RESULT: THE PAGE DISPLAYS WITHOUT THE FORM

Comment: Please show what code you have in your views for these forms. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show what you have tried and how it differs from your expected output.

Comment: Take a look at the `form-wizzard` in django-form-tools (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer so I put the complete code